# Identify multiple people in images and count the frequency

Tags: object-detection, faster-rcnn

I have multiple images posted by a user and I am interested to know how many times each unique person appears in the user's photos. For instance, the user might post photos of himself/herself with other people and I am interested to know how many times other people appear in the user's photos.

Have been researching on object detection but it seems that object detection techniques does not seem to answer the requirement. Could I ask if there are any ways to approach this problem?